# Spring subflow from main flow for each row retrieved from DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to create two flows where the main flow will poll the database and the subflow with the results from the mainFlow(which are required to be filtered as well) need to call the subFlow for each row and then create a file poller for each row retrieved.

**Requirement:**

1. Poll Database
2. Convert to a POJO(say Worker.java)
3. For each worker create a flow which listens to folder configured in worker java

**Main Flow**

```
final CustomJDBCMessageSource customJDBCMessageSource = this.jdbcMessageSource();
final IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(customJDBCMessageSource, //
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(pollInterval).maxMessagesPerPoll(1) //
                            .errorChannel(customErrorChannel()))) //
                    .handle((payload, headers) -> filterPayload(payload, headers))
                    .publishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), s -> s.subscribe(this.registerSubFlow(workerEntry))).get();
    
            flowContext.registration(flow).register().getId();
        }

public CustomJDBCMessageSource jdbcMessageSource() {
        final CustomJDBCMessageSource source = new CustomJDBCMessageSource(getDataSource(), "SELECT * FROM FMR_WORKERS");
        return source;
    }

    public class CustomJDBCMessageSource extends JdbcPollingChannelAdapter {
        public CustomJDBCMessageSource(DataSource dataSource, String selectQuery) {
            super(dataSource, selectQuery);
        }
    }
```

In the above snippet filterPayload method should transform my Message Object to a Worker Object based on some conditions so i would like to call that to a different method.
But though i say handle the flow is getting called to registerSubFlow where it is failing since the object is null.

**SubFlow**

```
private IntegrationFlow registerSubFlow(WorkerEntry workerEntry) {
    final AtomicInteger atomicFlowIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);

    final int flowIndex = atomicFlowIndex.getAndIncrement();

    S3WorkEntry s3WorkEntry = new S3WorkEntry();

    final CustomFileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource = this.fileReadingMessageSource(s3WorkEntry);
    configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("fileReadingMessageSource-" + flowIndex, fileReadingMessageSource);
    fileReadingMessageSource.setBeanFactory(configurableBeanFactory);

    fileReadingMessageSource.onInit();

    final IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource, //
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(s3WorkEntry.getPollInterval()).maxMessagesPerPoll(1) //
                    .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor(flowIndex, s3WorkEntry)) //
                    // c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(entry.getPollInterval()) //
                    // send errors to customErrorChanel to suppress default errorChannel to which
                    // default LoggingHandler subscribers
                    .errorChannel(customErrorChannel()))) //
            .channel(new DirectChannel()) //
            .get();

    flowContext.registration(flow).register().getId();
    return flow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `s.subscribe()` is called during initialization phase, not at runtime. You should be sure that you really send a message to some channel (or call gateway) with the content of your `handle()` result.

You also need to revise your JDBC flow. It is not clear why would one register it dynamically, but not as a regular singleton bean.

There is no need to call `registerSingleton()` (and `setBeanFactory()`). The `IntegrationFlow` processor does that for us.

Comment: Thank you @Artem Bilan i will try to use gateway. For dynamic registration, i'm trying to register a file listener dynamically as its details will be maintained in the database and one can update the details in it(create/update/delete). The one which i'm writing is by updating the previous implementation and they have registerSingleton with the following comments
"springboot over 2.0.8 duplicate instantiation of PROTOTYPE MessageSource bean, to address this problem, register bean on the fly using BeanFactory", so i'm guessing there might be some bug and to resolve that above snippet was done.

Comment: As I said: I may understand the reason for dynamic file pollers since that info you really may took from DB. What is not clear why would one register a poller for DB dynamically, but not as a single one for that specific table? That Boot version is too old, consider to remove that `registerSingleton`. Technically your `fileReadingMessageSource()` method must not be a bean and Spring Integration will register one (or two) for you.

Comment: Apologies misunderstood ur previous comment, but i'm not calling the registerSingleton for JDBC, i have updated the ticket with the calling methods and customJDBMessageSource variable initiation.